# Tkinter window won't open?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a basic calculator with Tkinter, but when I run the program the window doesn't open and there isn't any error message. Here's the code(the program is'nt finished yet).

```
from Tkinter import *

Calculette=Tk()
Calculette.title("Calculette")
Chiffres=StringVar

B7=Button(Calculette, text="7").grid(column=0, row=1)
B8=Button(Calculette, text="8").grid(column=1, row=1)
B9=Button(Calculette, text="9").grid(column=2, row=1)

B4=Button(Calculette, text="4").grid(column=0, row=2)
B5=Button(Calculette, text="5").grid(column=1, row=2)
B6=Button(Calculette, text="6").grid(column=2, row=2)

B1=Button(Calculette, text="1").grid(column=0, row=3)
B2=Button(Calculette, text="2").grid(column=1, row=3)
B3=Button(Calculette, text="3").grid(column=2, row=3)

Bfois=Button(Calculette, text="x").grid(column=3, row=3)
Bmoins=Button(Calculette, text="-").grid(column=3, row=2)
Bdivision=Button(Calculette, text="/").grid(column=3, row=4)
Bplus=Button(Calculette, text="+").grid(column=3, row=1)
Begal=Button(Calculette, text="=").grid(column=3, row=5)

Affichage=Entry(Calculette, textvariable=Chiffres).grid(column=0, row=0)

Calculette.mainloop
```

Comment: Change `Calculette.mainloop` to `Calculette.mainloop()`. And `Chiffres=StringVar` to `Chiffres=StringVar()`.

Comment: Please learn the basics of Python first. Tkinter requires that you at least understand what classes are, what a class' attribute is and what functions are and how to call them. GUI programming is relatively complicated, so it may be better if you start from the very basics of Python programming and gradually move to more complicated stuff.

Comment: In addition to the problems @Aran-Fey mentioned, all those variables are going to be `None`—like most Python methods that mutate the object instead of creating a new one, `grid` doesn't return `self`.